# Back-end performance testing for apache wicket

Tags: wicket, load-testing, performance-testing

We create a app based on the apache wicket and I'm now working on the performance testing for it.
I'm familiar with Jmeter so it's my first choice as the load generate tool for the back end performance testing. But, looks I can't record some "ajax call" actions from our app according to the wicket's behavior.

I'm also using Grinder, but it does not work as well.

I'm now thing using the HtmlUnit instead of Jmeter to do the back-end web app performance load testing.

So does anyone have better choice?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like jVisualVM in jdk/bin (1.6+?), also JVM Monitor eclipse plugin works fine for me

we are also doing performance testing of wicket page rendering, seen many comparisons over the web, but cannot get even close to it, on average desktop with 100 threads we get like 2-10 times more memory usage and 10-100 times longer response times, havily dependant on parameters

(compared to pure JSP)

any similar experience?

later spotted, that if all threads are pre-initialized, the response time is just 6-10x longer and memory usage is sometimes even lower (lets assume the same)

after server start i sent as many requests as many threads the server is designed to handle, give some time to rest :) and than it runs smoothly, but i dont like this ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which tool are you using for simulating the multi local threads calling your wicket app? Jmeter?

Comment: havent seen others but soapUI 4.0 looks easy to me

Comment: Jmeter or Grinder could be even better for web based loading testing. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: then we run the same test on 8x UltraSPARC (14GB mem for a proc.pair) and it was the same like JSP, just consuming 3x more processor time :)

Comment: but back to the point, soapUI is good because it is so light (big difference against ***htmlUnit*** for example), which is good if there is no other choice then running server and pseudo-clients on one machine

Comment: **soapUI** is ok for me as well. Just check the soapUI's documents and find it supports the http request since 3.6. I'm out of date. :( One thing I put my coin on Jmeter is we can easily invoke the source codes of it and load our perf scripts without GUI interface. That would be even be lightweight to the client side.